# DOM manipulation with document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

I have noticed this method works only when [0] is inserted, however, I can't find its purpose or explanation in syntax documentation.  What does this do, and why does the code not function without it?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "pink"
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a list so you access it by giving it an index. You use 0 in this case, because there is only one body tag in a page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, a collection of all the elements that match the tag. Since it's a collection, not a single element, you need to specify which items in the collection you want to operate on. A `NodeList` is array-like, so you use subscripts to access individual elements in the collection -- `[0]` means the first one. If you want to do something to all the matching elements, you would use a `for` loop:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

In the case of `body`, you know that there will only be one of them, so there's no need for this, you just index it explicitly with `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a collection (array) of elements that match the tag name provided. It does this even if there is only one element that matches the tag name. When you provide an integer to the method result, you are addressing a specific element within the array. For basic information on arrays, look here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp